# Measuring bandwidth usage through untrusted proxy service

Tags: http, http-proxy

Internet traffic for my office is being routed like this:

Devices -> router -> untrusted proxy service -> internet.

I'm being charged for bandwidth used through the proxy. Is there any way to accurately measure bandwidth usage at my modem? How would I know if the proxy is adding hidden data to http responses in order to inflate my monthly usage stats?

For example: I send a get request to example.com/, the normal response body would be "OK", but my proxy changes the response body to " Ok abcdefg<\span>

Any way go detect this?

Comment: The typical approach when you don't trust an invoice for any service is to ask for a detailed itemized bill and/or access to the raw usage data. Alternatively if you don't trust the service provider,leave.

Comment: If I had the raw usage how would I know if the proxy has added data? Leaving the proxy is not an option.